# Mongo DB is unable to find docs by date if date has some added offset time

Tags: java, mongodb

MongoDB stores date in GMT. I wanted date in IST. So from java driver I added 1980000 to current date before saving document to MongoDB. Now I need to query MongoDb get all documents before current date.

In java I did

```
dbCollection.find(new BasicDBObject("LastUpdatedOn",new BasicDBObject("$lte",new Date(new Date().getTime()+1980000)))
```

But it is unable to find my docs.
Although at shell prompt when I did `db.collectionname.distinct("LastUpdatedOn")` it gave me several values that are actually below my current TimeStamp.

The query that java driver is trying to fire on mongodb is

```
{"LastUpdatedOn" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-03-22T04:15:13.676Z"}}
```

and my distinct query on mongo shell is returning several docs that has timestamp

```
    ISODate("2015-02-03T03:39:50.824Z"),
    ISODate("2015-02-03T03:39:56.023Z"),
    ISODate("2015-02-03T03:39:56.434Z"),
    ISODate("2015-02-03T03:39:57.003Z"),
    ISODate("2015-02-03T03:39:57.230Z")
```

Please explain why Java is not able to find my docs on Mongo version 2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores the date as timestamp (unix time) which is seconds since 1.1.1970 GMT. This is a reference value and therefore free from any timezone. That, what you see is a representation of the time value.

Basically, 22.03.2015 10:26+01:00 (this is my current time) is the same as 22.03.2015 09:26+00:00. All these time representations lead to the same timestamp value of 1427016360000. Timezone is only relevant when parsing a time format into a timestamp or formatting a timestamp into a time format.

You should check using the mongodb trace logging (not `Query.toString`) what the driver really fires. You can enable the logging using

```
// Enable MongoDB logging in general
System.setProperty("DEBUG.MONGO", "true");

// Enable DB operation tracing
System.setProperty("DB.TRACE", "true");
```